# Correctly using CancelEventAgrs

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, event-handling

How should I correctly use CancelEventAgrs/CancelEventHandler?

Does checking `e.Cancel` will return always the "right" result, even if the event eventually could consume some time?

```
Class Foo
  Public Event Deleting As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler

  Private myObjectsToDelete As List(Of Object)

  Function DoDelete() As Boolean
    Dim e As New System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs
    ' Suppose a time consumming check '
    RaiseEvent Deleting(myObjectsToDelete, e)

    If e.Cancel Then
      Return False
    Else
      myObjectsToDelete.Clear()
      Return True
    End If
  End Function
End Class

Class Bar
  Private WithEvents myFoo As Foo

  Private Sub myFoo_Deleting( _
        sender As Object,
        e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles myFoo.Deleting

    Dim objectsList As List(Of Object) = TryCast(sender, List(Of Object))
    Dim objectsToDeleteOK As New List(Of Object)
    For Each o In objectsList
      If CheckIfCanBeDeleted(o) Then
        objectsToDeleteOK.Add(o)
      End If
    Next o

  End Sub

  Private Function CheckIfCanBeDeleted(o As Object) As Boolean
    Dim result As Boolean
    ' TIME CONSUMMING CHECK '
    Return result
  End Function

End Class
```

PS.
I put C# tag, because interested in a general .NET view, not just a VB.NET one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does checking e.Cancel will return always the "right" result, even if the event eventually could consume some time?

Are you worried that `DoDelete` will test the value of `e.Cancel` before the execution of the event handlers is complete?

Raising the event is a blocking operation, so the execution of `DoDelete` won't continue until all handlers have been executed. So yes, `e.Cancel` will always return the value set by the handlers, even if the handlers take some time to execute.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `e.Cancel` to `True`, then yes. Your handler does not appear to be setting it. If you have multiple handlers handling that event, then the last one to change `e.Cancel` wins.

Comment: I am not sure about if `RaiseEvent Deleting(myObjectsToDelete, e)` **waits** until all check are performed.

Comment: Raise event waits on the thread that it was raised on. All handlers will be called on that thread as an event ultimately results in method calls. If those calls must set `e.Cancel` on a different thread, then you have to synchronize the results back.